# How to detect popup blocker in IE

Tags: javascript

I am using this code to detect popup blocker of browser. Current script working fine in chrome and firefox but not in IE browser. In IE weather popup is on or off alert is detecting by IE.

---

```
 <html>
 <head>
  <title>Contentverse Online</title>
  </head>
  <script>
   function closeCurrentWindow() {
        var version=0;
        if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE")!=-1){
                    var temp=navigator.appVersion.split("MSIE");
                    version=parseFloat(temp[1]);
        }
        if (version>=5.5 && version<=6) {
                    this.focus();
                    self.opener = this;
                    self.close();
        } else {
                    window.open('','_parent','');
                    window.close();
        }
    }
</script>
 <body>
 <script>

     var newWin = window.open("Sign.asp?Home=C:/Program Files/ViewWise                Online&VWOFlavor=Full","myWindow",'top=0,left=0,width='+screen.width+',height='+screen.height+',status=yes,resizable=no,scrollbars=yes');

     if (!newWin || newWin.closed || typeof newWin.closed == 'undefined' || newWin.outerHeight == 0){
     alert("Please Enable Popup For this Site...");

    } 
 else
  {

 }
   </script>
  </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem in IE? Can you re-phrase that last sentence?

Comment: alert("Please Enable Popup For this Site..."); this alert shoud display when pop is on but it is displaying again and again weather it is on or off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation for IE's popup blocker](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784600%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) the only thing you need to check is if `newWin` is `null`:

> Web page authors should check for a NULL return value for any windows
>   that you open. This will indicate whether the pop-up window opened
>   successfully and allow you to handle either case.
>
> If your software opens windows automatically, they will be blocked.
>   Look for alternative ways of doing the same thing as described earlier
>   in this document. The best way to open a window is to have the
>   customer click a link or graphical element.

Perhaps you should split the condition for showing the alert into several checks, with one of the tests directed specifically for IE (and don't add `||...` in that same `if`). Write other tests (maybe also checking for null and other things as well) for whatever browsers they're supposed to be used with.

In general though, **don't use popups**...

Comment: Try to write simple code that works in IE (test only if newWin is null). Then if it doesn't work in some other browser, add other conditions.